# How to give permanent UACs permission to an application?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, uac, microsoft-store

I've installed some programs that always require permission to run (like aText, Cmder, clover .... etc), I gave them the permissions they needed once I installed them, but whenever I try to run them again, they just request the same permission again over and over to the level that it's irritating.

I saw a solution somewhere, and it's obvious from the raging conversation that occured there that the solution provided is either outdated or wasn't helpful, beside, the solution was about a shortcut of the program, why?? I'd like to give the software itself the permission without creating a shortcut (like in android), also, how will this aply to Microsoft store apps??? , here is the link:

https://www.eightforums.com/threads/how-to-give-permanent-uacs-permission-to-an-application.32624/

I also don't want to turn off my User Account Control Setting (UACS) completely because I want it to stop anything that I haven't given permission to from running. But it's incredibly irritating that every single time I try to launch an application, I have to give it permission to run.

Comment: 1) Open a PowerShell window as administrator. 2) Launch the programs that require elevation from that window. Since the process that launched them is already elevated, you will only get 1 UAC prompt (in step 1).

Answer (score 0):

It depends up the application.

Some applications (e.g. Tree Size) have two shortcuts (admin and standard).  The Standard operation cannot work with system files and go to secured folders because it does not have permission. The Admin operation has complete access. But you need to OK Admin operation with UAC.

Some applications (e.g. Sync Back Pro) have Manifest files and you can use the Admin Manifest file to always run Sync Back without asking for credentials.  This works very well if the software vendor provides the option.

Some applications (e.g. Comm View) will not run unless you provide Admin Credentials when you run it. Even enabling the Admin setting in the Advanced Properties of the shortcut does not permanently change this.

Try for your app to enable Admin Mode in the Advanced properties of the App Shortcut. It may work; it may not.

***So*** if the application insists on Admin Credentials, you will have to provide Admin Credentials every time.